# TypeScript literal type generator

Tags: typescript, types

I am trying to create an action generator that would return correct typings.
So I have the following code:

```js
const createAsyncActionWithTypes = (prefix: string, name: string) => [
    `@${prefix}/${name}_REQUEST`,
    `@${prefix}/${name}_SUCCESS`,
    `@${prefix}/${name}_FAILURE`,
  ] as const;

const requestPersonActions = createAsyncActionWithTypes('person', 'GET_PERSON');
```

This function makes `requestPersonActions` be of the following type:

```js
const requestPersonActions: readonly [
  `@${string}/${string}_REQUEST`, 
  `@${string}/${string}_SUCCESS`, 
  `@${string}/${string}_FAILURE`
]
```

What I want is for `createAsyncActionWithTypes` function to generate the following type:

```js
const requestPersonActions: readonly [
  `@person/GET_PERSON_REQUEST`, 
  `@person/GET_PERSON_SUCCESS`, 
  `@person/GET_PERSON_FAILURE`
]
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)

```
const createAsyncActionWithTypes = <T extends string, U extends string>(prefix: T, name: U) => [
    `@${prefix}/${name}_REQUEST`,
    `@${prefix}/${name}_SUCCESS`,
    `@${prefix}/${name}_FAILURE`,
  ] as const;

const requestPersonActions = createAsyncActionWithTypes('person', 'GET_PERSON');
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=7&ssc=81&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRBBCBPMx3CgEtwB1QqACwBUsAHRCGAXhgB4qZEAPNMAE0bR4hMAHMANDACqnHon6CowsQD4AFLSQAzQlwBcMKpLDIAtogNSAlMxUwA2gCgYLmAAMAAgBIA3psQ6XAC%20APS%20JuZBAPoASgCiAIpScQDKVG7izq6evv6BoeFmiNEpUgDCZakpGVkuOX7augU%20EcVRAGLoAJIAMlLxNS4AujDIjKCQUADcjo4T0DBIAI4ArgxQAAqI8BDg%20ETgjCwIKGiYOHgExGBklDT0EGoA5PQ74E%20STwDicVRRG3EYikAPIAOSeVimQA)